Continuity of Map and product
Assume $X$ is metric space and $Y$ is a closed set. Assume there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $Y$ in $X$ and a continuous map $f:U\times I\rightarrow X$ such that $f(n,1)=n$ for all $n$, if $n\notin Y$, then $f(n,t)\notin Y$ for all $t\neq 0$. Does $f$ extend to a continuous map $X\times I\rightarrow X$?
I thought of defining $G:X\times I\rightarrow X$ by $G(x,t)=x$ for all $x\notin U$ and on $U$, $G(u,t)=f(u,t)$. But I havent been able to show continuity.

How can $f(n,t)\not\in Y$ if the codomain of $f$ is $Y$?

Did you mean for $f$ to have codomain $X$, or $U$ (and similar for $G$)? As it is written right now there are no such maps $f$.

@BenSteffan edited, sorry

@Keen-ameteur edited

Unfortunately, your statement is not true in general. I will give you a counterexample.
Let $X=[-1,1]$ with the usual metric, let $Y=\{-1,1\}$ and let $U=A\cup B$ where $A=[-1,0)$ and $B=(0,1]$. Now, consider the maps
$$f_A:I\times A\to X,\quad (s,x)\mapsto\begin{cases}(1-2s)x-s,&0\leq s\leq 1/2,\\ (2s-1)x+s-1,&1/2\leq s\leq 1,\end{cases}$$
and
$$f_B:I\times B\to X,\quad (s,x)\mapsto\begin{cases}(1-2s)x+s,&0\leq s\leq 1/2,\\ (2s-1)x+1-s,& 1/2\leq s\leq 1.\end{cases}$$
Intuitively, $f_A$ slides every point in $(-1,0]$ to $-1/2$ and back again, whereas $f_B$ slides every point in $(0,1]$ to $1/2$ and back again. It is clear that $f_A$ and $f_B$ are continuous. Since $A$ and $B$ are open and disjoint, we can glue $f_A$ and $f_B$ together to a continuous map $f:I\times U\to X$. I claim that this $f$ does not have a continuous extension to the whole space $I\times X$. Suppose that it does, denote this extension by $\bar f:I\times X\to X$ and consider the point $\bar f(1/2,0)$. There exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $d((s,x),(1/2,0))<\delta$, then $d(\bar f(s,x),\bar f(1/2,0))<1/2$. Then,
$$d(\bar f(1/2,-\delta/2),\bar f(1/2,\delta/2))\leq d(\bar f(1/2,-\delta/2),\bar f(1/2,0))+d(\bar f(1/2,0),\bar f(1/2,\delta/2))\leq 1$$
which is a contradiction since $\bar f(1/2,-\delta/2)=-1$ and $\bar f(1/2,\delta/2)=1$. This finishes our proof.
